# Manual call React Router Prompt

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using React Router Prompt to show confirm before navigating away. Now I want to use the same confirm component for another feature on the same page, so how to manual trigger the Prompt

```
<Prompt when={props.when} />
```

Comment: The `Prompt` is rendered into the DOM and is triggered when navigating away from or reload the page. What more do you need to know to use it?

Answer (score 0):

So you could use when an argument in Prompt to do the custom triggering just like this,

```
`<Prompt when={formIsHalfFilledOut} message="Are you sure?" />`
```

When is evaluated to true or false, pass when={true} or when={false} to prevent or allow navigation accordingly!

Comment: I don't move to another page, for example, I want to trigger when I select a checkbox option